# R code Boost "fatal error: boost/detail/endian.hpp: No such file

Tags: boost, simd

Simple example from RcppNT2 that generates "fatal error: boost/detail/endian.hpp: No such file or directory #include <boost/detail/endian.hpp>". I downloaded boost C++ version 1.82. I want it all contained to one file. It may have too many headers.

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-IC:/Users/.../boost_1_82_0/include")       
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-LC:/Users/.../boost_1_82_0/lib -lboost_regex") 

sourceCpp(code="

#include <RcppNT2.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/endian.hpp>
#include <boost/detail/endian.hpp>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppNT2;

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNT2)]]

// Define a functor -- a C++ class which defines a templated 
// 'function call' operator -- to perform the addition of two pieces of data.
struct add_two {
  template <typename T>
  T operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
  return lhs + rhs;
  }
 };

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double simd_sum(NumericVector x) {
// Pass the functor to 'simdReduce()'. This is an
// algorithm provided by RcppNT2, which makes it
// easy to apply nt2-style functor definitions
// across a range of data.
return simdReduce(x.begin(), x.end(), 0.0, add_two());
}")
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no question but the asker apparently wants to build boost into her process, and the compile stops because the compiler can't find:

#include <boost/detail/endian.hpp>

First of all, you will have better luck building things as they are intended to be built.  you can probably build boost as a static link library by itself.  this solves a bunch of problems because then you are using the build system as the boost devs intended.  it also makes it easier to trouble shoot your own builds.  a static link means it is part of your executable and will not break when boost changes.

But to get past this obstacle, discover if you do have endian.hpp on your system somewhere.  Make sure the one you find is the appropriate instance of that file.  then you will have /actual/path/.../endian.hpp
see if the last part matches:/actual/path/.../boost/detail/endian.hpp
if so, then you need an I directive in your compile line
"-I /actual/path/..."

if not you can just hard code the full path in the file
#include "/actual/path/.../endian.hpp"

that should get you over that particular hump.